# Does pytorch register modules that are assigned to object properties?

Tags: python, pytorch

Say I have a module like:

```
class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cnn = CNN(params)
```

And then I do:

```
module = MyModule()
module.cnn = CNN(some_other_params)
```

Is the replacement registered? Will there be any nasty side effects down the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is the standard way to reassign attributes. Whether there are nasty side effects depends on whether your replacement is specified compatibly.

Comment: "depends on whether your replacement is specified compatibily". As in whether the python code is compatible? ie the correct methods and properties are there and behave as intended? (I'm trying to clarify that there's no hidden PyTorch monster)

Comment: @alexandersoare As in whether the input and output dimensions match the preceding and proceeding layer etc. There may be other requirements, depending on how the model is defined. There is no catch-all list of requisites here, it depends on the model.